# How to sub-select or sub-zoom in a d3js chart?

Tags: d3.js, charts

I wont to use d3js to do some kind of subselection based on the user actions. I’m not even sure how to call this (sub-selection, zoomin-selection …) so I will explain:

1. STEP:
   I have collection of books. Each book have country, state and city where it is written. So on the pie-chart I want to show t how many books are written in each country. That’s easy. But ..
2. STEP:
   the user should click on one country (one segment of the pie chart) and then see in some kind of popup see all states for that country, when he choose one states the pie-chart should transform to show how many books are in the each state of the initial country. Beside that somewhere (doesn’t matter where) should be a link to the books so that user can navigate one step back.
3. STEP 3:
   is the same as step 2, just that the user zoomin from state to city – and the a link should show the country so that user can navigate one step back.

Becouse I don’t even know how this is called I was unable to find anything alike. 
Can anyone give a hint or a working example – I doesn’t have to be a pie-chart – could be any chart of d3js – I need just to figure out how this sub zoomin/selection works.
TIA

Comment: Something like [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/kerryrodden/7090426)?

Comment: It shoud go something like this, just instead of using another group i want to use onoter sub-group. [Link](https://live.zoomdata.com/zoomdata/visualization?__target=embedded&key=52265abb6abdbcaa8c217789#51db7ad4e4b04caf9ab346db-51db7ad4e4b04caf9ab346d5)

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks! It's very close - if not even better - i will take a deep look at it.